# Rubymine gem manager エラー　Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 4.1.6 から 4.2.0 にアップデートして rubymine を起動すると画像の警告が出て、`install missing gems` を押すと下記のエラーが出ます。

`bundle install` と `bundle update` はしており、`gem list` を確認すると正しいバージョンがインストールされていますが、改善されません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/ruby mkrf_conf.rb 
Installing base gem
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/debase-0.1.3/.gitignore
/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:369:in `initialize'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:369:in `open'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:369:in `block (2 levels) in extract_tar_gz'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:64:in `each'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:351:in `block in extract_tar_gz'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:442:in `block in open_tar_gz'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:439:in `wrap'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:439:in `open_tar_gz'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:350:in `extract_tar_gz'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:331:in `block (2 levels) in extract_files'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:64:in `each'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:328:in `block in extract_files'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package/file_source.rb:29:in `open'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package/file_source.rb:29:in `with_read_io'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:325:in `extract_files'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:722:in `extract_files'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:248:in `install'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:166:in `block in install'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:150:in `each'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:150:in `install'
  /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:394:in `install'
  mkrf_conf.rb:35:in `rescue in <main>'
  mkrf_conf.rb:28:in `<main>'

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/l7/507yf4tj3yd7mjxxgschz5y00000gn/T/bundler20150513-20255-s3vvs/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.30/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.30 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/l7/507yf4tj3yd7mjxxgschz5y00000gn/T/bundler20150513-20255-s3vvs/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.30/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.30/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing ruby-debug-ide (0.4.30), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install ruby-debug-ide -v '0.4.30'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

#### ruby-debug-ide -v '0.4.30 コメントアウト後のエラー

```
Error:[rake --tasks] /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find debase-0.1.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler.rb:121:in `setup'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
Error:[rake --prereqs] /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find debase-0.1.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler.rb:121:in `setup'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

Comment: 魚を与えるか、魚の釣り方を教えるか、という言葉があります。前者であれば「たぶん答えはこうですよ」と教えることですが、長い目で見れば後者の方がご自身のためになります。というわけで、このコメントでは「魚の釣り方」を伝えます。スタックトレースをよく読んでください。そこにヒントになりそうな文言が含まれています。まずはそのヒントを元に必要なアクションを取ってみてください。それでもエラーが出るなら、またスタックトレースやエラーメッセージからヒントを探してください。それを何度か繰り返すと問題が解決しているはずです。

Comment: ruby-debug-ide -v '0.4.30をコメントアウトしたのですが、別のエラーになってしまいました。

Comment: おぉー直りました。ありがとう御座います。gem 'debase'とgem 'ruby-debug-ide'を削除したら直りました。多分必要ないんですよね

Answer (score 1):

コメント欄でのアドバイスを元に、`gem 'debase'` と `gem 'ruby-debug-ide'` の記述を削除したら直りました。多分必要ないんですよね。

---

*この投稿は @opps さんのコメント の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*